# OpenMPI on Xcode (Mac OS Catalina)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, mpi, openmpi

successfully ran brew install open-mpi

however, when running a cpp file in xcode, the line "#include <mpi.h>" creates an error, stating mpi.h file not found

is there any solution?

Comment: the easiest fix is to use the `mpicxx` wrapper instead of the `g++` compiler.

Comment: Run `mpicxx --showme:help`. It will show you a list of options that you can use to obtain the path to the include and lib directories and additional flags you need to pass to the compiler and the linker. Put those in the relevant parts of your Xcode project's configuration.